# DAX query to check values in multiple rows

Tags: powerpivot, dax

Need help to create a DAX for the below.

EventID CFStatus    ManualRowStatus CalculatedRowStatus

1       Paid        Count
1       Waived      Ignore
2       Paid        Count
2       Paid        Count
3       Waived      Count
3       Waived      Count

If CFStatus has both 'Paid' and 'Waived' for a given EventID, then CalculatedRowStatus field should be marked as "Count" for the "Paid" row  and "Ignore" for the "Waived" row.

For all other combinations, CalculatedRow status should be marked as "Count".

In short, CalculatedRowStatus column should show same result as that of ManualRowStatus as shown in the picture.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
Ramesh.

Comment: Sorry, I cant upload image due to lack of enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of a standard bit of excel type nested IF() and a CALCULATE() that checks for records of that event id with a paid status:

```
=
IF (
   [CFStatus] = "Paid",
   "Count",
    IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'table' ),
        FILTER (
            'table',
            [EventID] = EARLIER ( [EventID] )
                && [CFStatus] = "Paid"
        )
    )
        > 0,
    "Ignore",
    "Count"
)
)
```